# How to clear GPU memory WITHOUT restarting runtime in Google Colaboratory (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I want to run hyperparameter tuning for a Neural Style Transfer algorithm which results in having a for-loop in which my model outputs an image generated with different hyperparameters per iteration.

It is running in Google Colaboratory using GPU runtime.
At runtime, I get at some point an error that says that my GPU memory is almost full and then the program stops.

So I was thinking maybe there is a way to clear or reset the GPU memory after some specific number of iterations so that the program can normally terminate (going through all the iterations in the for-loop, not just e.g. 1500 of 3000 because of full GPU memory)

I already tried this piece of code which I find somewhere online:

```
# Reset Keras Session
def reset_keras():
    sess = get_session()
    clear_session()
    sess.close()
    sess = get_session()

    try:
        del classifier # this is from global space - change this as you need
    except:
        pass

    #print(gc.collect()) # if it's done something you should see a number being outputted

    # use the same config as you used to create the session
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 1
    config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
    set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Answer (score 17):

in tensorflow you van use numba library:

```
!pip install numba

from numba import cuda 
device = cuda.get_current_device()
device.reset()
```

Comment: this is the working answer

Comment: After doing this i got ```RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered```

Comment: This reset my enitre Colab environemnt, so if you are like me and had a bunch of files you were cooking for hours but were not able to successfully save, don't do this as you will ruin your experiment!

Answer (score 6):

You may run the command "!nvidia-smi" inside a cell in the notebook, and kill the process id for the GPU like "!kill process_id".
Try using simpler data structures, like dictionaries, vectors.

if you are using pytorch, run the command `torch.cuda.clear_cache`

Comment: Sometimes, there are no process_id to kill

Comment: the command is torch.cuda.empty_cache()  as of june 2023

Answer (score 6):

If you're using torch, `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` would be the way, which should follow an `nvidia-smi` to make sure you can't directly kill the process.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: I tried this. but, the resources usage widget continued to be in the red. Did not change at all. Does that mean, it has cleared the cache or not?