# Can i clear up gpu vram in colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, gpt-2, fine-tuning, vram

I'm trying to use aitextgen to finetune 774M gpt 2 on a dataset. unfortunately, no matter what i do, training fails because there are only 80 mb of vram available. how can i clear the vram without restarting the runtime and maybe prevent the vram from being full?

Answer (score 10):

Another solution can be using these code snippets.

1.

```
!pip install numba
```

2. Then:

```
from numba import cuda
# all of your code and execution
cuda.select_device(0)
cuda.close()
```

Your problem is discussed in Tensorflow official github. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36465

**Update:** @alchemy reported this to be  unrecoverable in terms of turning on.
You can try below code.

```
device = cuda.get_current_device() 
device.reset()
```

Comment: well i hope it will be solved soon then, i'm tired of having to finetune 124M gpt 2 only

Comment: this is unrecoverable.. use `device = cuda.get_current_device();
device.reset()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/73517694/4240654

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the command `!nvidia-smi` inside a notebook block.
2. Look for the process id for the GPU that is unnecessary for you to remove for cleaning up vram. Then run the command `!kill process_id`

It should help you.

Comment: there are no processes. never

Comment: Just to recheck, is the setting "GPU" turned on from "Notebook settings" option? Because it should not be happening iff the gpu is not being on and used.

Comment: No no. Don't get me wrong. And don't get offended. I am trying to help you. I already provided another solution below. You can check that.