# Is that possible to reset / empty / free up Google Colab notebook GPU VRAM? Without restarting the session

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Currently I am trying to run Whisper on my Google Colab.

It throws a GPU memory error. However after error is thrown, GPU ram usage is still maximum

There are i don't know maybe 100 questions but none of the given answers are working

I need a way to free up GPU memory without restarting the session so avoid all downloaded data to be erased

Here take a look at the current status of the notebook. You see error thrown but GPU ram is still max

[image]

And here the entire code of the Google Colab

```
!pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
!pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git 

import os

# Add folders
checkContentFolder = os.path.exists("content")
checkDownLoadFolder = os.path.exists("download")
if not checkContentFolder:
  os.mkdir("content")
if not checkDownLoadFolder:
  os.mkdir("download")


import whisper
from pathlib import Path
from whisper.utils import write_srt
import pandas as pd

def main():

    # transcribe the audio
    #model = whisper.load_model("large")
    model = whisper.load_model("large-v1")
    #model = whisper.load_model("../input/whisper2/large-v1.pt")
    transcribe_name_begin="oop";
    sub_folder_name="/download/oop/"
    import os

    if not os.path.isdir(sub_folder_name):
        os.makedirs(sub_folder_name)
        
    _compression_ratio_threshold = 2.4
    for lectureId in range(142, 143):
        transcribePath=f"../content/"+transcribe_name_begin+str(lectureId)+".mp3";
        result = model.transcribe(transcribePath,
                                  language="en",
                                  beam_size=9,
                                  initial_prompt="Welcome to the Software Engineering Courses channel.",
                                  best_of=9,verbose=True,temperature=0.0,compression_ratio_threshold=_compression_ratio_threshold)
        #result = model.transcribe("../input/whisper2/lecture_"+str(lectureId)+".mp3",language="en",beam_size=5,initial_prompt="Welcome to the Software Engineering Courses channel.",best_of=5,verbose=True,temperature=0.0)

        # save SRT

        language = result["language"]
        sub_name = sub_folder_name+transcribe_name_begin+str(lectureId)+".srt"
        with open(sub_name, "w", encoding="utf-8") as srt:
            write_srt(result["segments"], file=srt)

        # Save output
        writing_lut = {
            '.txt': whisper.utils.write_txt,
            '.vtt': whisper.utils.write_vtt,
            '.srt': whisper.utils.write_txt,
        }

        output_type="All"

        if output_type == "All":
            for suffix, write_suffix in writing_lut.items():
                transcript_local_path =sub_folder_name+transcribe_name_begin+str(lectureId) +suffix
                with open(transcript_local_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    write_suffix(result["segments"], file=f)
                try:
                    transcript_drive_path =file_name
                except:
                    print(f"**Transcript file created: {transcript_local_path}**")
        else:
            transcript_local_path =sub_folder_name+transcribe_name_begin+str(lectureId) +output_type

            with open(transcript_local_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                writing_lut[output_type](result["segments"], file=f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, the solution is not to "reset" GPU RAM (whatever this means), but to use less RAM, you can start by decreasing the batch size during training/inference.

Comment: You could for example use one of the smaller whisper models, not the "large" one.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i will test with reducing beam size. however since ram is not freed-up not able to. so my question is still valid

Comment: I think you are pretty much screwed up, because since the crash, the state of pytorch is undefined and this causes more problems, as you already figured out, I suggest that you just restart the session and download the dataset into a place where it will not vanish across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904476/how-to-clear-gpu-memory-without-restarting-runtime-in-google-colaboratory-tenso) work for my:

```
from numba import cuda 

device = cuda.get_current_device()
device.reset()
```

But sometimes session was crashed after reset :(

Comment: this resets but after we are not able to use gpu anymore. here the error RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

Comment: here the error message after executing your code : https://i.imgur.com/dW6DdOs.png

Comment: Probably there a link to object in GPU memory. May be model instance. Before using hack like this you must try clear memory in a regular way like `model = None` or `del model` for all objects in GPU memory include input and output tensors.

Comment: this is why i hate python. if it was .net i wouldn't have such error. will test those 2